# Can I use my existing .Net 4.0 Class Libraries on WinRT Metro Style Applications for Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

I just started diving into Metro Style application development and I realized that there is no framework targeted when I look at the properties of the application.

So, can I use my existing .Net 4.0 Class Libraries (or previous ones) on WinRT Metro Stype Applications for Windows 8?

For example, I would like to get the `Autofac` and use it but I am not sure if it would be a right fit.

**Edit**

I think it is actually targeting .Net Framework Core 4.5.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: http://dougseven.com/2011/09/15/a-bad-picture-is-worth-a-thousand-long-discussions/

Comment: @DarinDimitrov so, to sum up that I am not allowed to use any other private API outside of the Metro Profile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst a number of WinRT APIs are quite similar to the .NET APIs, you cannot directly share class libraries. This is the same situation with WPF, Silverlight and Silverlight for Windows Phone, where the APIs are similar but class libraries are not interchangeable. You can however target these three platforms if you use the [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) (PCL). I guess there is a chance that the PCL might support WinRT in the future, however, I am sure it will be much like XBox360 support, where only the core libraries can beshared.

Comment: Not that the question is about WPF, but you say WPF is in the same boat whereas it is not; it runs on the standard .NET framework, and can reference standard .NET code.