# Using a C++ CLR Library in a C# Metro Application

Tags: c++, .net, twitter, microsoft-metro, clr

I have been writing some applications for windows metro in c# and have been trying to create a twitter program, using the tweet sharp library, that will allow the user to tweet and view the tweets of the people they are following and check for updates in a background task.

The problem that I was having is I wanted to use c++ for sorted maps. The sorted maps was, at least what I found, to be the quickest way to sort through and organize the large amounts of tweeters and their tweets. Which is especially helpful because of the constraints that background tasks have when it comes to accessing the CPU.

But I found that my CLR libraries couldn't be used in my metro application because of the improper build target for the dll file.

Is it possible to use a CLR library with WinRT applications and deploy them on the app store or does anyone know of an alternative way to manage these large amounts of tweets considering the CPU constraints.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056452/can-i-use-my-existing-net-4-0-class-libraries-on-winrt-metro-style-applications) post it currently is not possible.
Apart from that, WinRT has a different system for processing metadata in apps and class libraries.

For one, you can look at [.NET for Windows Store apps overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx) and secondly about [CLR integration (C++/CX)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699899.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, I actually found out that it may be possible to integrate a .net subset + CLR with my .net WinRT application. The only problem is that if my app used a CLR library it wouldn't pass the app certification process though could be used and debugged locally. [Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/033b581c-462d-4c39-8eb0-7357665dd5ce)